# Transmission dont start

Tags: transmission

I have tried to completely remove it through "purge" and reinstall, but in the end it does not open either.  If I put "transmission-gtk" in the terminal, the response I get is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".  I don't know what this means and what can I do.

Comment: We don't know your OS/release which somewhat limits us.  Have you explored the crash file in `/var/crash`? as the top of the file is rather readable (before it turns into dump).  What package are you using (`apt-cache policy`) and does it suit your *unstated* OS/release? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, just install Transmission via Flatpak and everything works fine now.  What is the problem with the other type of installation?  Don't know